# Gson write to nested objects

Tags: java, json, gson

In Gson how do I write to subfields/nested objects. This is my current code:

```
    Path usersPath = Paths.get("src/users.json");
    Gson usersGson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();


    try (BufferedReader usersReader = Files.newBufferedReader(usersPath);
        BufferedWriter usersWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(usersPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
        JsonObject usersObject = usersGson.fromJson(usersReader, JsonObject.class);
        
        usersObject.addProperty("example", 123);
        usersGson.toJson(usersObject, usersWriter);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How would I make the users.json look like this:

```
{
  "example1": {
    "example2": {
      "example3": 4
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling the JSON as a string (therfore skipping the file reading and writing, just for this demo), I will show two basic approaches:

**1) Use Java maps**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

...

Map<String, Integer> ex3 = new HashMap();
ex3.put("example3", 4);
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> ex2 = new HashMap();
ex2.put("example2", ex3);
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> ex1 = new HashMap();
ex1.put("example1", ex2);
        
String json = new Gson().toJson(ex1);
System.out.println(json);
```

In this case we manually build nested maps. The output is:

```
{"example1":{"example2":{"example3":4}}}
```

**2) Use a POJO (or POJOs)**

In this case I will use one class containing 2 nested classes - but they could be 3 separate classes if you prefer.

The POJO is:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class NestingPojo {

    @SerializedName("example1")
    private Example1 example1;

    public static class Example1 {

        @SerializedName("example2")
        private Example2 example2;

        public static class Example2 {

            @SerializedName("example3")
            private Integer example3;

            public Integer getExample3() {
                return example3;
            }

            public void setExample3(Integer example3) {
                this.example3 = example3;
            }

        }

        public Example2 getExample2() {
            return example2;
        }

        public void setExample2(Example2 example2) {
            this.example2 = example2;
        }

    }

    public Example1 getExample1() {
        return example1;
    }

    public void setExample1(Example1 example1) {
        this.example1 = example1;
    }

}
```

Strictly speaking, the annotations are not needed in this case, because the field names used by the POJO match the required JSON names.

We can generate the JSON as follows:

```
NestingPojo nestingPojo = new NestingPojo();
NestingPojo.Example1 example1 = new NestingPojo.Example1();
nestingPojo.setExample1(example1);
NestingPojo.Example1.Example2 example2 = new NestingPojo.Example1.Example2();
example2.setExample3(4);
example1.setExample2(example2);
                
String s = new Gson().toJson(nestingPojo);
System.out.println(s);
```

This generates the same JSON output as the first example.

*In both cases, the common thread is building Java objects which correspond to the hierarchical structure of the expected JSON output.*

The first approach can become unwieldy fairly quickly, for more complex examples. The second approach has more flexibility, in my opinion, as you are working with tailored classes.

Neither approach uses `JsonObject`. It's just a preference on my part to use Java objects for this type of task.

**Update**

In case `JsonObject` is required or preferred, here is an example:

```
JsonObject json3 = new JsonObject();
json3.addProperty("example3", 4);
JsonObject json2 = new JsonObject();
json2.add("example2", json3);
JsonObject json1 = new JsonObject();
json1.add("example1", json2);
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(json1));
```

This builds the nested elements starting from the innermost object.

**Update 2**

Writing the data to a file can be done as follows - in this example, I am using the `ex1` object from above (the nested maps):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
try ( FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c:/tmp/ex1.json")) {
    gson.toJson(ex1, fw);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle the exception here
}
```

In this case, I used `GsonBuilder` so I can specify the "pretty printing" option (which you don't need, but is helpful).

This creates a file containing the following formatted JSON:

```
{
  "example1": {
    "example2": {
      "example3": 4
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the first method how would I save it to a file?

Comment: Example added to the end of the answer.